# What is the differences between purchasing Harvard Business Review PDF and reading the article?

Tags: journals, website, abstract

I was reading this Harvard Business Review article, [The Making of an Expert](http://hbr.org/2007/07/the-making-of-an-expert/ar/1) and they were offering a PDF purchase.

Are there major differences between the content of the PDF and the free article?

Answer (score 5):

Many publisher offer a teaser - an excerpt of an article - as an advert for the full article. The teaser may contain the abstract, some graphics, maybe a lay summary or press release about the article, and so on.

In the case of your Harvard Business Review article, they let you read the first eight paragraphs, which gives you an idea of the article's content and style. The full article is about five times longer than that excerpt.

If you buy the pdf, you get the full article, together with its references, and any supplementary information. (though in this particular case, there are neither references nor supplementary information).

Note that five pages of text can get turned into nine pages within a journal, thanks to graphics and other materials that appear in the PDF, but don't appear in a text-only version: for example, in the PDF of the article in question, the first page consists of a single image.  The text-only version may or may not contain the side-bars that appear in the PDF ("Things to Look Out for When Judging Expertise").

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I can somehow see 5 pages of the article (rather than 8 paragraphs). Though in the book purchase page, it mentions there are 9 pages. What is going on?

Comment: Oh, I understand, I have a "limited access" account which grants me 4 free articles every month (including the one above). It still doesn't explain the differences in the number of pages (5 pages vs. 9 pages)

Comment: @user256021 I've updated the answer with a new final paragraph that addresses the difference in page length.

Answer (score 0):

EnergyNumbers' answer is quite complete. In this particular case of the HBR article, the link you provide leads to the first paragraphs of the article and not to the complete article. Notice that, after the first eight paragraphs (as well as at the beginning), the image of a key appears. This signifies that the rest (and likely most) of the article is "locked". Should you be interested to read the whole article, you are instructed to buy it - or, in the event that you are a HBR subscriber, to simply login.